# ECONNRESET while calling browser stack API from jenkins

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, supertest, browserstack

I am trying to automate the browser stack POST API to upload files into their custom media using SuperTest node js module.
API- https://api-cloud.browserstack.com//automate/upload-media
This absolutely works fine on my local machine, but not on jenkins. The Jenkins server is hosted on a virtual machine in same network.
Getting below error on Jenkins:

Error: read ECONNRESET
at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20)

Code:

```
    let request = supertest('https://api-cloud.browserstack.com');
    let response = await request
        .post('/automate/upload-media')
        .set(
            'Authorization',
            'Basic ' +'username':'access key'
            
        )
        .set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data')
        .attach('file', `/path/to/file/`);
```

Tried to add browser stack credentials to Jenkins Credential manager

Answer (score 0):

"Error: read ECONNRESET at TLSWrap.onStreamRead" tells that this has something to do with SSL/TLS certificate or network restriction issue.

There are few things you can try:

1. Check your Jenkins server has the necessary SSL certificates installed which may be blocking this API.
2. Do check if *.browserstack.com is whitelisted on your Jenkins machine's network on ports 443 & 80.
3. Compare the environment variables and other network related configurations between your local machine and Jenkins server machine.
4. Try to enable detailed debugging on Jenkins, so we can get more information around it.

Moreover, try to check that error on old StackOverflow you may get some useful help from there.

I hope this helps.